# How to get visible event for fixed positioned div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As per the layout of my webpage, I want to apply animations on some elements.

I have one fixed positioned element. I am using [inview.js](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview) to detect element visibility.

Once the page is loaded I log in the console: 'section2 visible' with 'section1 visible'.

I want it to print 'section2 visible' only when user is actually able to read the content.

How can I achieve this?

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2610rqxa/2/

js:

```
$('.section1').bind('inview', function(event, visible) {
    if (visible === true) {
        // element is now visible in the viewport
        console.log('section1 visible');
    } else {
        // element has gone out of viewport
        console.log('section1 not visible');
    }
});
$('.section2').bind('inview', function(event, visible) {
    if (visible === true) {
        // element is now visible in the viewport
        console.log('section2 visible');
    } else {
        // element has gone out of viewport
        console.log('section2 not visible');
    }
});
```

html :

```
<div class="section1">
Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!    
</div>
<div class="section2">
    <h1 class="header"></h1>
Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!     World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!   Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!
</div>
```

Comment: section2 does not go outside of the viewport, unlike section1. Therefore, when section2 does go outside of the viewport, section1 is visible.

Comment: `.section2` is within view of the viewport in your jsFiddle, so it is working as  expected. Maybe detect when `.section1` is `not visible` then do something with `.section2`.